# obtain time(hours, minutes) since post was uploaded and display the result in my web-page

Tags: javascript, html, time

I have a rather small part of my webpage that uses a definition list to display some of my posts i do on a irregular basis, and I thought it would be a nice thing to add the time feature to each post using Javascript.

**HTML**

```
<dl>    
<dt>Display the time here</dt>
<dd></dd>
<div id="centrated">
<p>Blank Space</p>
</div>
</dl>
```

The time should be based on the 'user' and not on my system.

Comment: Obviously the time since the post was made is the same for the user and the system, unlike the time at which the post was made.  Presumably you store in your database the system time the post was made, so to calculate the time since the post you need to use a comparison of system times.  I think you should probably be a bit more explicit about your question here.

Comment: I think i confused what i am planning here, ofcourse the time is based on my system since it will be my post. But what i meant is if the user is located in different tz, it should do some calculations to make sure it is considering the difference, + , -, or whatever.

Comment: The time difference is irrelevant if you want to show the time _since_ the post was made.  Is that a typo, and you want to show the time itself, and not the time difference?  In which case using UTC as @Tyanna suggests is a good solution.

Comment: Ok and how can i display the obtained time in my list?

Comment: @JamesGaunt can you answer please?

Comment: It's not clear what the question is.  If you're asking how to display the difference between two dates that you know, in hours and minutes, then one way would be to convert both dates to milliseconds using getTime(), and then take the difference and divide appropriately to get hours and minutes.

Comment: No I mean how to display whatever result i obtain using the time object, to display it in my webpage.

Comment: How to take the number of hours and minutes and put it on the page?  If you have this information on the server side then it depends on how you render the page on the server. If you have it on the client side then use jquery - e.g. $("#Story1 dl dt").html("hours:" + hours + ", minutes: " + minutes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're planning on retrieving the date/time of the post with what you've described here. But, javascript knows how to convert from UTC to local time of the browser.

So, if you create a new date from a string:

```
var d = new Date("2012-10-13T09:40:34.764Z");
alert(d);
```

It should show it in the local time for you. The `'Z'` at the end of the date says that it's in UTC time. Javasript knows how to work with that if you define the date that way. Just make sure you're saving your dates in UTC time.

Comment: Ok but can i leave the date out using the Date object? because I only want the time in hours and minutes.

Comment: @Drucker ~ yes, you can with some work: d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes();

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean something like

```
var UTCPostedTimeInMs = 1350050604350;
var timeSince = (new Date) - UTCPostedTimeInMs,
    secs = ~~(timeSince / 1000),
    mins = ~~(secs / 60),
    hrs = ~~(mins / 60),
    days = ~~(hrs / 24);

console.log('It has been', days, 'days', hrs % 24, 'hours', mins % 60, 'mins and', secs % 60, 'seconds since', new Date(UTCPostedTimeInMs));
// It has been 1 days 8 hours 6 mins and 12 seconds since Fri Oct 12 2012 15:03:24 GMT+0100 (BST)
```

---

**Edit**
To display in HTML give the element you want to append it to an *id* attribute

```
<dt id="post001Time">Display the time here</dt>
```

and then in JavaScript, however you want it formatted, e.g.

```
document.getElementById('post001Time').textContent = (hrs % 24) + ' hours and ' + (mins % 60) + ' ago.';
```

See [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qku6c/).

Comment: Yeah thats pretty close. So what exactly did you calculate in the UTCPostedTimeInMs? And how can i display the result in my HTML?

Comment: could you help me understand your post fully?

Comment: @Drucker `UTCPostedTimeInMs` is the number of ms since the Unix Epoch at the original time of posting, _January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT_, which is how computers calculate the date and time. You can [get it in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) using `(new Date).valueOf()`.
In php you can calculate it by `time() * 1000` (as the [php function returns seconds](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php), not ms)

Comment: just a quick one. Will it work for several posts using the same ID, or do I have to change something? Right now it only applies for one post in one page... when I apply to id to more than one post, it wont work.

Comment: @Drucker an _id_ must be unique.

Comment: So should it be enough to change to a class everywhere it will be used and change the script to look for the classname? e.g, getElementsByClassName('post001Time')

Comment: @Drucker, yes, class names don't have to be unique so you can get the elements you want this way. Additionally, if you put the `UTCPostedTimeInMs` value as a [_data-*_ attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-data-*) on those elements it would be easier to write the function as the information is readily available for each of those elements.

Comment: Could you take alook at it please because it is not working.

Comment: var UTCPostedTimeInMs = 1350050604350;
var timeSince = (new Date) - UTCPostedTimeInMs,
    secs  = ~~(timeSince / 1000),
    mins  = ~~(secs      / 60  ),
    hrs   = ~~(mins      / 60  ),
    days  = ~~(hrs       / 24  ),
    weeks = ~~(days      / 7   ),
    years = ~~(weeks     / 52  );
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('post001Time').textContent =
        (hrs % 24) + ' hours and ' +
        (mins % 60) + ' mins ago.';
}, false);
<dt class="post001Time">DATE</dt> Can you see anything wrong with this?

Comment: Please see http://jsfiddle.net/Qku6c/2/ . This has now become a different question to the one posted so if you need more help consider posting a new question.